# UITableView animations for a "lazy" UI design?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that allows the user to perform editing tasks.

Now, once a user has committed his change, the table view doesn't directly change the model and updates the table, rather "informs" the model what the user wants to do. The model in turn updates accordingly and then posts a notification that it has been changed.

As far as I've seen, I need to begin/end updates on the tableview and in between change the model to its' final form. My changes though, are asynchronous and cannot guarantee to update the model before 'tableview endupdates' is called.

Currently, each time I receive a 'model did change' notificaiton, I reload the entire table.

So, how can I really make cell animations (delete/insert) work?
Should the model fire a notification for each little change instead of the entire table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the old array used to display data and compare it with the new array. You can then animate any additions/deletions.
Also, unless you're doing something very fancy, you are not modifying the model but rather a set of data based on the model.